# Finding minimum by groups in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I've got data that looks like this:

```
User     PaymentType         Month
-----------------------------------
A       Early Payment          1
A       Early Payment          2
A       Early Payment          3
A       Outstanding            4
A       Outstanding            5
A       Outstanding            6
B       Early Payment          1
B       Early Payment          2
B       Early Payment          3
B       Outstanding            4
B       Outstanding            5
B       Outstanding            6
```

How can I create a calculation that returns only the minimum month of "Outstanding" `PaymentType` for each user which can be then put in as a new column in the data? I need to track when was the first "Outstanding" `PaymentType` made for every user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{ FIXED [User] : MIN(IIF([Payment Type] = 'Outstanding', [Month], NULL)) } = [Month]
```

That will give you a column that's true if it's the user's first month with an outstanding payment, and false otherwise. The data will look like this:

```
+------+---------------+-------+---------------------------+
| User | PaymentType   | Month | First Outstanding Payment |
+------+---------------+-------+---------------------------+
| A    | Early Payment | 1     | F                         |
| A    | Early Payment | 2     | F                         |
| A    | Early Payment | 3     | F                         |
| A    | Outstanding   | 4     | T                         |
| A    | Outstanding   | 5     | F                         |
| A    | Outstanding   | 6     | F                         |
| B    | Early Payment | 1     | F                         |
| B    | Early Payment | 2     | F                         |
| B    | Early Payment | 3     | F                         |
| B    | Outstanding   | 4     | T                         |
| B    | Outstanding   | 5     | F                         |
| B    | Outstanding   | 6     | F                         |
+------+---------------+-------+---------------------------+
```

Note that this is for the exact data you gave us. If your month is, for example, a date field (as opposed to simply a number), or if you add years to your data, or if you have multiple payments per month, this formula will have to be adjusted. However, this gives you the basic idea of how to go about calculating what you're looking for, and it shouldn't be hard to update the calculation to fit your needs.

---

If a bool isn't what you're looking for, you can just take out the conditional to have the field hold the month number of the first outstanding payment.

```
{ FIXED [User] : MIN(IIF([Payment Type] = 'Outstanding', [Month], NULL)) }
```

In which case, your data will look like this:

```
+------+---------------+-------+---------------------------+
| User | PaymentType   | Month | First Outstanding Payment |
+------+---------------+-------+---------------------------+
| A    | Early Payment | 1     | 4                         |
| A    | Early Payment | 2     | 4                         |
| A    | Early Payment | 3     | 4                         |
| A    | Outstanding   | 4     | 4                         |
| A    | Outstanding   | 5     | 4                         |
| A    | Outstanding   | 6     | 4                         |
| B    | Early Payment | 1     | 4                         |
| B    | Early Payment | 2     | 4                         |
| B    | Early Payment | 3     | 4                         |
| B    | Outstanding   | 4     | 4                         |
| B    | Outstanding   | 5     | 4                         |
| B    | Outstanding   | 6     | 4                         |
+------+---------------+-------+---------------------------+
```